# Angular 2 ngOnchange event is getting called irrective of any change

Tags: angular, typescript

Helo All,

I am facing a issue, as I am new in Angular so it may be a something I am missing.

In my application, in one of the child component ngOnChanges is getting called irrespective on any change, In below screen shot you will find all the currentValues and previousvalues properties of changes object is same.

Let me know if I am missing something.

Please also refer below code

Thanks

import { Component, Input, SimpleChanges, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { OnChanges, OnDestroy } from @angular/core/src/metadata/lifecycle_hooks';

```
@Component({
selector: 'xxxxxx',
templateUrl: './result.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./result.component.css']
```

})

```
export class ResultComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges, OnDestroy {


@Input()
searchResults: SearchResults.SearchResult;

@Input()
searchText: string;

@Input()
loading: boolean = false;

ngOnInit() {
    var logger = "stop me debugger";
}


ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {

    if (changes.searchResults && !changes.searchResults.firstChange) {


    }
}


ngOnDestroy(): void {
    var logger = "stop me debugger";
}



constructor() {


}
```

}

[image]

Comment: add code instead of image

Comment: There's nothing in your provided code fragment that should lead to this ngOnChanges call.

Answer (score 0):

The lifecycle hook `ngOnChanges`:

> Respond when Angular (re)sets data-bound input properties. The method receives a `SimpleChanges` object of current and previous property values.
>   Called before `ngOnInit()` and whenever one or more data-bound input properties change.
>
> [Angular Lifecycle Hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-sequence)

Because of this and some of your properties are inputs, `ngOnChanges` gets called. That's also why the `previousValue` **and** the `currentValue` of the `SimpleChanges` object are  `undefined`.

Comment: So that was my question, I haven't made any changes in input properties,you can also see both previous and current values are same.
So if previous and current values are same then ngOnchanges are not supposed to call?

Comment: That is correct, but `ngOnChanges` always gets called before `ngOnInit`, no matter if the values change.